# How to Change the font color of a listview

Tags: android, listview

This is the code for my list view how can I change the color of the listview

```
public class eat extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_eat);

        String [] Hotels ={"Deer Park","Araliya","Royal Lotus","Kandalama"};
        ListAdapter hoteladapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,Hotels);
        ListView hotellist= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv);
        hotellist.setAdapter(hoteladapter);

       // hotellist.setc
    }
```

Comment: Simply use `textView.setColor(R.color.your_color);` in .class file with every textView you have set in listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to somehow gain access to the TextView object that holds your text.

You have a few options:

- Use a custom adapter
- Use a custom item layout
- Go quick and dirty way:

  ```
  ListAdapter hoteladapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
          android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Hotels) {
      @Override
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
          View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
          TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
          tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);

          return view;
      }
  };
  ```

Comment: I would not recommend the latter, since it's not reusing rows thus is resource inefficient.

Comment: @Marcus you're wrong. ListAdapter re-uses the rows automatically. Multiple calls to `findViewById`, however, can be expensive but since the list contains only 4 items, the difference will be pretty much invisible.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify your list item layout as below

yourtextviewlayout.xml:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:textColor="@color/your_color"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

and provide this layout to your `ArrayAdapter`

```
ListAdapter hoteladapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.yourtextviewlayout,Hotels);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to implement your own `ListAdapter` that fills your data items into custom views. There are tons of tutorials on the web. A Google search will help.